# iOs 7 website as homescreen icon crashes on start

Tags: html, ios7, iphone-5, web-sql, html5-appcache

We have a html5 application. When its started on iOS 7 on iPhone 5, from the home screen (as a fullscreen application). The phone restarts.

We're using webSql, and the appCache. The application never reaches a point where it does Ajax calls.

Has anyone experienced anything similar, know of any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue with our html 5 app. Our application was creating a websql db with an initial size of 25Mb. We resolved it by creating it with a size less than 5Mb. Apparently IOS7 + safari has a bug when websql database is created initially with a size greatar than 5Mb.

Here is the link which explains the issue:
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review